# Read all line passed by console

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-processing

I need to get all lines in a text file that is passed by the console in python.
For example:

I had a file named website.txt that has 3 lines:

```
https://www.amazon.com/
https://www.amazon.com/
https://www.hbo.com/
```

This file will be passed by the console when the app is executed.

Example:
In a Linux terminal:

```
cat /home/eric/Documentos/websites.txt | python ./application/app.py
```

So, each line of this file should be read and for each site, I will be the request.

How can I make it?

Comment: Take a look at [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html) module.

Comment: Thanks a lot @wim  I can use sys.stdin in a loop for!

Comment: Note that in a *nix shell, a pipe `|` doesn't pass a file, it passes binary data, which in this case is lines of text.

Comment: Yes @wjandrea this link had my answer! My problem here was that I don't knew how to do this question correctly, so, to find an answer was necessary to explain here with an example. 

Thanks a lot for you answer!

Comment: you should get every line separatelly with normal `input()` or `sys.stdin.readline()` - so you have to run it in loop. And if you want to send to another program connected by `|`  then you need only `print()` or `sys.stdout.write()` - eventually you can need `print( ..., flush=True)`

Comment: Instead of `cat file.txt | python app.py` consider `python app.py < file.txt`. It uses one less process, and it's quicker to type.